# Get the mid-point value from Gompertz equation

Tags: r, function

```
time <- 1:12
y <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,34,69,100,100)
mdl <- gcFitModel(time,y,control = grofit.control(fit.opt = "m", model.type = "gompertz"))
```

I get my parameters from the above mdl to fit the gompertz equation

```
y <- A* exp(-exp(mu * e * (lambda - time)/mu + 1))

mu <- 36.162016
lambda <- 7.9800164
A <- 100
time <- 1:12
```

`time` here is in a step of 15 days. For e.g `time = 1` implies mid-day of a 15 day period, `time 2` implies mid day of the next 15 days period, time 3 implies implies the mid-day of the next 15 days period and so on.

I fitted the following function:

```
  e <- exp(1)
  y <- 100 * exp(-exp(mu * e * (lambda - time)/mu + 1))
  plot(time,y)
```

[image]

The lambda controls the movement along the x-axis. 
I am looking to modify this curve so that I get more data points by converting the ids into weeks i.e instead of mid-point of every 15 days,  I want to get y for every 7 days. How can I do this?

Comment: why not provide a denser time vector: `time <- (1:24)/2`.

Comment: or `time <- seq(1, 12, by = 0.5)` or `time <- seq(1, 2, length.out = 24)`

Comment: BTW, I don't see you fitting anything in your code example, but I guess you've omitted that part and are only showing the plotting routines?

Comment: @MauritsEvers thank you. I have provided an example of how I fitted the function

Comment: @Crop89 If I understand you correctly, this is a plotting issue (rather than a fitting problem). Does my solution below not answer your question?

Comment: I think the solution by @missuse `time <- (1:24)/2` works better for me since now it splits the x-axis into points of week.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't include any fitting routines, so I am assuming this is a question about plotting.

Here is an example of a plot with 100 points between `time = 1` and `time = 12`.

```
time <- seq(1, 12, length.out = 100);

mu <- 34.55844
y <- 100 * exp(-exp(mu * e * (3 - time)/mu + 1))
plot(time,y)
```

[image]